# How can I cut and cap a hot water supply line that has no shut-off after the HWT?

Tags: plumbing

I have an old hot water supply line that is no longer being used and I want to cut and cap it for later use. The problem I have is that it has no shut down after the hot water tank. My other hot water feeds have shutoffs. What should I do to cut and cap without a flood?

Comment: Turn off the water at the street?

Answer (score 3):

You should have a shut-off valve *before* your hot water tank (your main entry valve), shut that one off, open all the faucets in your house to drain the hot water from your system, do your repair, turn on the valve that is before your hot water tank and turn off all your faucets.

You could keep a bucket closeby, just to get what's left in the pipe.

Comment: It's also safest to turn off the water heater during this work. Also, if someone opens turns on both the hot and the cold water in a faucet, the cold water could flow the wrong way into the hot water pipes. So, you may want to just turn off all of the water.